# Error while trying to install JupyterLab with pip

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, command-prompt, jupyter-lab

I have just installed Anaconda on a new machine (Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit). As I try to install JupyterLab with `pip`, I always get the following error:

```
Collecting ipykernel (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)'),)': /simple/ipykernel/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)'),)': /simple/ipykernel/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)'),)': /simple/ipykernel/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)'),)': /simple/ipykernel/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)'),)': /simple/ipykernel/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ipykernel/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/ipykernel/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipykernel (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ipykernel (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab)
```

I see that `ipykernel` is involved, but what is the problem here?

Comment: Looks like the relevant line is `There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate`. Are you able to install other packages?

Comment: Also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

Comment: @FlyingTeller I am not able to download any other package - I always get this same message. Is it a problem of admin credentials?

Comment: Have you tried installing with `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`?